# Adding GPU to an existing VM instance on Google Compute Engine Slows Performance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I created a VM instance with Google Compute Engine with a single initial GPU and would like to add a second GPU of the same type. The VM instance is using Windows Server 2016, has 8 CPUS and 52GB of memory. I have followed the steps to add a GPU at the following location:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/add-gpus

When using the updated VM instance, the performance is very slow (Click on a window/button and 10 seconds later it opens). The CPU does not appear to be heavily utilized. If I remove the GPU so that only a single GPU is used, the performance goes back to normal.

Am I missing a step (maybe updating something in windows)?

Comment: GPUs require device drivers in order to [function properly](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/#restrictions). NVIDIA GPUs running on Google Compute Engine Windows Server instances must use the  driver versions, NVIDIA 411.98 driver or greater
Can you confirm that you have installed the required [drivers](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/add-gpus#install-gpu-driver).

Comment: Yes, the drivers are installed, I am able to use a single NVidia V100 in applications. I have found a round-about way to improve performance when adding and removing GPUS, which is to run the command "GCESysprep" from the command prompt. This seems to reset the image and cause it it to run addititional scripts the first time restarting. The side effect is that it seems to reset many windows configurations to the VM.

Comment: I have tried to add a second GPU in Windows server 2016 and didn't face any slow performance.
Are you experiencing the issue immediately after boot up or later? The system could take time to load all applications so that may cause an initial slowness. Are you running any memory intensive applications? Are you using an image from GCP or are you using a custom image for the VM?

Comment: I am creating the instance from the console on the GCP. For example, I am selecting 8 vCPU, 30GB memory, 1 NVidia Tesla V100, for the boot disk using Windows server 2016 Datacenter with a 150GB SSD. Once this is created, it is accessed through chrome remote desktop and a basic application like task manager is accessed (normal performance). The instance is then stopped and edited in the console to add a second V100. The instance is then restarted and accessed through chrome remote desktop and task manager is opened. Clicking through the tabs is painfully slow and seems to slow down over time.

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue. I would recommend opening an issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) with regards to this . Please be reminded to mention all the relevant details and reproduction steps if any.